# Datatable creating duplicate no-named cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTables 1.9.2 with `bStateSave: true`. When I have this the datatable creates cookie to save the current settings of the table.

What I see is that its creating one cookie with name `SpryMedia_DataTables_orderListDataPane_data_abc` and value as a JSON. One more cookie with no name but value as `SpryMedia_DataTables_orderListDataPane_data_abc`.

This is giving problem when datatable is trying to update the cookie status. Any idea why this is happening?